# How can a Docker image target arm64 if its base image does not?

Tags: docker, docker-build, multiplatform

I am using an image that was not built for `linux/arm64`:

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-7.2-alpine-3.17
```

> image with reference mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-7.2-alpine-3.17 was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm64, actual: linux/amd64

And indeed, if I inspect the image, its architecture is `amd64`

```
docker image inspect --format '{{.Architecture}}' mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-7.2-alpine-3.17
```

> amd64

But if I use the image as a base image in my `Dockerfile`...

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:lts-7.2-alpine-3.17
```

...and then build it...

```
docker build --platform linux/arm64  --tag test .
```

...and then inspect the image, its architecture is `arm64`

```
docker image inspect --format '{{.Architecture}}' test:latest
```

> amd64

So does the architecture of an image only reflect the value of the `--platform` argument at the time of build, and not the 'intrinsic' architecture?